# What is the word for using an (potentially) obsolete object as basis of design for something which replaces the object?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for using an (potentially) obsolete object as basis of design for something which replaces the object?

For example, the idea of using the textured paper design for notes app or dials in digital watch.

Comment: Making a design appear (ie the look) [retro](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retro)? Or designing the function of a new object based on older obsolete objects?

Comment: I had heard a word for it somewhere but could not recall. Finally found the word. It is "skeuomorph".

Comment: I just cut & pasted "word for using obsolete object as basis of design for something which replaces the object" into a Google search. Unsurprisingly, the first result was this very question on ELL, but the *second* result had the heading ***Skeuomorph - Wikipedia***, and enough text on the "snippet view" to show this was obviously the relevant term. I suggest in future you search Google for the text of your question title before actually *posting* a question like this here.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually tried searching on google for a while. Just wasn’t using the right keywords I suppose, and got it right when composing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word I was searching for is "skeuomorph".

Answer (score 0):

Recreate or revamp?

That question is so specific though xD

Comment: Sorry, if it sounded too specific. I had heard it somewhere but could not recall. Finally found the word. It is "skeuomorph"

Comment: Answers to word requests should quote definitions from reputable dictionaries and link to them.